# Angular 7 multiple query string, how to

Tags: c#, typescript, angular-material, url-routing, angular7

I have an asp.net method that accepts a list of items as a parameter. The function works and has been tested. Now this method is being consumed by Angular. My question is, how can I successfully pass multiple parameters from within Angular?

Essentially, I'm trying to achieve this:

```
localhost:4200/download?item=fname&item=lname&item=cc
```

The values are being passed from Angular material design check boxes.

> Asp.Net Core

```
[HttpGet("downloadbooks")]
public IActionResult Download(IList<string> item)
{
  //omitted for simplicity
}
```

> Angular Service

```
downloadfunction(item: any = []){
  return this.http.get(url + `books/downloadbooks?item=${item}`,  { headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }), responseType: 'blob'}
    );
}
```

> Angular TS

```
fname;
fnameChecked = false;

lname;
lnameChecked = false;

cc;
ccChecked = false;


  onfnameChecked() {
    this.fname= ""
    if (this.fnameChecked) {
      this.fname = "fName"
    }
  }

  onlnameChecked() {
    this.lname= ""
    if (this.lnameChecked) {
      this.lname = "lName"
    }
  }

 onccChecked() {
    this.cc= ""
    if (this.ccChecked) {
      this.cc= "cc"
    }
  }

downloadBooks(){

//I want to pass multiple parameters within the dowloadfunction()
//only one parameter is passed at the moment.

 this.downloadService.downloadfunction(this.fname).subscribe(blob => {
 link.href= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
})
}
```

> Angular html

```
    <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" name="fnameChecked" [(ngModel)]="fnameChecked" [checked]="fnameChecked" (change)="onfnameChecked()">First name</mat-checkbox>

    <br />
    <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" name="lnameChecked" [(ngModel)]=" lnameChecked " [checked]=" lnameChecked " (change)="onlnameChecked()">Last Name </mat-checkbox>
    <br />
<mat-checkbox class="example-margin" name="ccChecked" [(ngModel)]="ccChecked " [checked]=" ccChecked " (change)="onccChecked()">Credit card</mat-checkbox>

  <button mat-raised-button [mat-dialog-close]="" color="primary" (click)="downloadBooks()"><a [target]="'_blank'">Submit</a></button>
```

Comment: Why not make a concatenated string of your parameters and then just attach that to the URL in the service?

Comment: @Chris Thank you for the feedback. How would that look like?

Comment: Just pass `HttpParams` with all your parameters in the `params` in your `http.get` call.

Comment: @JessedeWit I appreciate your comment. I was looking at the angular documentation. I couldn't find an example. Could you please show me how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [HttpParams](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams) to achieve that.

```
const item = [fname, lname, cc];
const options = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
  params: new HttpParams().set('item', JSON.stringify(item))
};

this.http.get(url, options)
```

Comment: the `param1` and `param2` only seem to work when you have something like this => `localhost:5000/api/book?param1=item1&param2=item2`

What I'm looking for is `localhost:5000/api/book?item=fname&item=lname&item=cc`

Is there another way of writing this?

Comment: Got it. So you would actually want to pass an array as the value of item?

Comment: that's exactly what im looking for. How can I pass an array?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. This unfortunately didn't do it for me. The plan is to use checkboxes to pass values to the function. So if I choose 1 check box, I am expecting this: `localhost:5000/api/book?item=fname`. If I choose 2 check boxes, I would expect this: `localhost:5000/api/book?item=fname&item=lname` and so on.

Comment: Ok. Then I suggest you to take a look at these issues: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11662 and https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/11373

Comment: I appreciate the feed back you've given me. This has finally worked out!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways you can use [HttpParams](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams)

### Option 1

using **set** (i.e. overwrite)

`?item=fname,lname,cc`

```
const items = [fname, lname, cc];

this.http.get(url, { params: new HttpParams().set('item', items) })
```

### Option 2

using **append** (by reassigning the params variable because HttpParams is immutable)

`?item=fname&item=lname&item=cc`

```
const items = [fname, lname, cc];

let params = new HttpParams();
items.forEach(i => (params = params.append('item', i)))
this.http.get(url, { params });
```